# When editing an answer, the OP highlight on comments changes users when comments are expanded

Tags: bug, status-review, comments, edits, highlighting

When using the full page editor (like someone without editing privileges), I noticed that the highlight to show who is the "original poster" on comments will swap between the answer OP and the question OP after clicking "Show X more comments". (On sites like MSE this highlight is blue.)

Here is a link to [edit an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/284037/edit) where you can see this (no matter your rep).

Here is a screenshot showing the answer owner being highlighted when the comments aren't expanded (left), and the question owner being highlighted when they are (right):

[image: not expanded vs expanded]

Comment: The title is incomprehensible (at least in isolation).

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Better than "Who's blue? Sometimes it's me, sometimes you". Or maybe rhyming would have been better.

Comment: This is a weird one... comments are always highlighted to show the OP of the *question* but on answer revision history pages, the OP of the answer is the one who gets highlighted... (OP revisions are blue, everyone else is grey)... so I'm not actually sure what the behavior *should* be here.